# Ruby on Rails: What does "<%" and "<%=" mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, show, symbols, execute

What are the differences between "<%" and "<%="? How do you know which to use? I'm teaching myself and one of the tutorials I'm using listed the above symbol sets.

Answer (score 2):

You must use <%= %> for instructions whose output you want to display in your view, and use <% %> otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

`<%= %>` use to output something
`<% %>` use to add your conditions for example